# OpenSSL on Windows stops in the middle of the the genrsa process

Tags: windows, security, openssl

I've been trying to run the code below to generate keys and every time it stops in the middle of the process.

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048
```

I'm on Windows and have tried it a few times. Every time I see something like the picture below and then it stops.

[image]

Comment: Wild guess: It might be using user-generated events as a source of its entropy for random number generation.  Moving mouse, typing on keyboard, or otherwise using computer normally and see if the progress advances.

Comment: It's not that. Moving the mouse or typing things in doesn't help.

Comment: Try hitting the key *1* - 4 times, then *Enter*, then again *1* - 4 times, then *Enter*, after you see the above image, to see if it makes any difference. Btw, what's its version? (`openssl version -a`).

Comment: Version is: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
It treats any key I hit as the next command after I exit by CTRL+C

Comment: Are you running it under cygwin , strangely i see the $ prompt...?

Comment: I'm doing it with Git Bash.